# How to remove elements from array other then x or y in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove all the elements from the array other then x or y (if available)

**Example:**
**Case 1:**

```
let array = ['a','b','c','d','x','y']
```

So,in that case, other then x and y, I want to remove all the other elements.
**output:** `['x','y']`

**Case 2:**

```
let array = ['a','b','c','d','x']
```

In this case, other then x, I want to remove all the other elements.
**output:** `['x']`

**Case 3:**

```
let array = ['a','b','c','d']
```

In this case, I want to remove all the elements.
**output:** `[ ]`

Couldn't find a better approach to go ahead with that. Any help will be appreciated.
THANK YOU :)

Comment: Magic word: array filter. `array.filter(e => ['x', 'y'].includes(e))`

Comment: `array = array.filter(e => e === "x" || e === "y")` or `array = array.filter(e => ["x", "y"].includes(e))`

Comment: `output=[]; if(array.includes("x")) output.push("x"); if(array.includes("y")) output.push("y");`

Comment: To keep all others than x and y just negate the expression `array.filter(e => !['x', 'y'].includes(e))`.

Comment: @Sohan ... do you want to mutate the array that you are operating on or are you completely  satisfied with the many solutions that promote the negated `filter` approach which of course returns a new array instance and leaves the original array untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare the allowed strings in inside an alone array and then use the `filter` method on the array.

```
const allowedStrings = ['x', 'y'];

let array = ['a','b','c','d','x','y'].filter(
   item => allowedStrings.includes(item)
);`
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter` and `Array.includes`.

```
let array = ['a','b','c','d','x','y'].filter(item => ['x','y'].includes(item));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the following command:

```
array = array.filter(v => v==="x" || v==="y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // create the array

// filter out every letter not included in the given array
console.log(array.filter((letter) => ['a', 'b'].includes(letter)));

// you can also filter out every letter that *is* is the given array
console.log(array.filter((letter) => !['a', 'b'].includes(letter)));
```